# Korrekte Beistrichsetzung in "immer wenn ich"

Tags: punctuation, comma

> Ich habe heute immer wenn ich einen Vogel gesehen habe, an dich gedacht.

Wo würdet ihr hier noch einen Beistrich setzen?

Answer (score 8):

Mehrteilige Fügungen werden in folgenden [Ausnahmen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K127) fakultativ durch ein Komma getrennt:

> - angenommen[,] dass
> - ausgenommen[,] wenn
> - besonders[,] wenn
> - geschweige[,] dass
> - geschweige denn[,] dass
> - gleichviel[,] ob
> - je nachdem[,] ob

In allen anderen Fällen wird hier üblicherweise kein Komma gesetzt. Im Beispielsatz muss aber der Nebensatz mit einem Komma getrennt werden:

> Ich habe heute, immer wenn ich einen Vogel gesehen habe, an dich gedacht.

Häufig wird *"immer wenn"* allerdings an den Satzanfang gestellt:

> Immer wenn ich heute einen Vogel gesehen habe, habe ich an dich gedacht.

Answer (score 6):

Der Satz braucht auf jeden Fall ein weiteres Komma, weil ein Nebensatz eingeschoben ist, und dieser sowohl am Anfang als auch am Ende [durch ein Komma vom Hauptsatz getrennt werden muss](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K121).
Die [mehrteilige Fügung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K127) "immer wenn" kann durch ein Komma getrennt werden, deswegen ist das Komma dort am sinnvollsten:

> Ich habe heute immer, wenn ich einen Vogel gesehen habe, an dich gedacht.

Comment: Nachdem es darum geht, ob diese Fügung getrennt werden soll oder nicht, ist die Begründung "es kann dort getrennt werden" unzureichend für die Entscheidung. Beide Kommata entsprechen nicht meinem Sprachrhythmus.

Comment: Ich würde den Nebensatz entweder umformulieren und das "Immer wenn" an den Satzanfang stellen, wie von Takkat vorgestellt, oder aber genau wie elena trennen, nämlich zwischen "immer" und "wenn".